# Ubuntu 16.04 Terminal not opening after upgarding python from 2.7 to 3.6 and then again setting 2.7 as default

Tags: python, ubuntu-16.04, gnome-terminal

[I used this tutorial to upgrade to python 3.6](https://rajputankit22.medium.com/upgrade-python-2-7-to-3-6-and-3-7-in-ubuntu-97d2727bf911) since I couldn't use pip and many answers said that pip dropped the support of python 2.7. But now I can't open terminal. Some answers suggested going back to default version will help. But in update alternatives list there was no python2.7, so I installed it and set it as default but still the terminal won't open. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I think this discussion can solve your problem https://askubuntu.com/questions/1132349/terminal-not-opening-up-after-upgrading-python-to-3-7

Comment: @Exploore X thank you sooooo much that worked. Finally I can open my terminal.

Comment: @Exploore X If you can write that as an answer...I can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 16.04 is optimized for python 2.7 and python 3.5.
Perhaps when you installed Python 3.6, Ubuntu's default Python setting was set to 3.6.
So if you lower the python default setting to python 2.7 or python 3.5 it should work fine.

Comment: I later set it to Python 2.7 but its still not working. Does it matter if it is python 2.7.8 or 2.7.12? Because right now my default is python 2.7.12. Is there any other alternative to make my terminal work?